# Hash string with sha-256 in Java Groovy on JMeter

Tags: python, java, groovy, jmeter

I'm trying to convert a Python script that calculates a SHA-256 hash into Java Groovy for use in JMeter. However, I'm encountering differences in the hash values generated between Python and Groovy. I would appreciate some guidance on how to achieve consistent results.

Python Code:

```py
import hashlib

def get256SHA(string):
    m = hashlib.sha256()
    m.update(string.encode('utf-8'))
    return m.hexdigest()

hashedValue = get256SHA("string")
```

Java Groovy Code:

```
import java.security.MessageDigest

String get256SHA(String string) {
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("UTF-8")
    byte[] digest = md.digest(bytes)
    StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer()

    for (byte b : digest) {
        hexString.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff))
    }

    return hexString.toString()
}

String input = "string"
String hashedValue = get256SHA(input)
vars.put("hashedValue", hashedValue)
```

In the Java Groovy code, I've attempted to replicate the Python logic to calculate a SHA-256 hash. However, the resulting hash values are not matching between Python and Groovy implementations. Could someone help me identify the potential differences causing this inconsistency and suggest corrections to the Java Groovy code?

After debug again, I got the code below is not wrong, the wrong is my input not trim. And this is the long way, you can try below answer, it's a good way.

Comment: Why don't you include the results (or a few bytes from the start).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code. What are your inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [__digest() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) in JMeter which can encrypt the value using various algorithms.

In your case it would be as simple as:

```
${__digest(SHA-256,string,,,hashedValue)}
```

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article to learn more about JMeter Functions concept.

If you still want to use Groovy the easiest would be going for [DigestUtils.sha256Hex()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html#sha256Hex-java.lang.String-) function:

```
vars.put('hashedValue', org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex('string'))
```